# ionic run -l-c not working with cordova localwebserver

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an application where I am using wkwebview engine with cordova-labs-local-webserver plugin, when the application launches then I see the splash screen and after that I see the white screen with the message saying cordovalocalwebserver tag src is not http://localhost:[port] but (xxx.xxx..:8100)

When I build the same using the xcode then everything works fine, I need to run ionic run in order to see the console outputs.